# Why is this code showing error -"runtime error 13 type mismatch"?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am trying to form a pivot table with the mentioned fields. The code that i am using is this-

```
Sub summary()
Worksheets("Raw Data").Activate
Dim ptc As PivotCache
Dim pt As PivotTable
Set ptc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=Range("A1").CurrentRegion)
Worksheets.Add
Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Add(ptc, Range("A4"))
pt.PivotFields("Invoice_Date").Orientation = xlRowField
pt.PivotFields("Region").Orientation = xlRowField
pt.PivotFields("Sales_Amount").Orientation = xlDataField
End Sub
```

The data is in Sheet 2 which is renamed as "Raw Data". and i am trying to form the pivot table in a new worksheet.

Comment: Which line are you getting the error on?

Comment: `ptc` should be declared as `PivotCache` not `Pivotcaches`

Comment: nice one @Rory. Missed that :)

Comment: Thanks @Rory. I did correct it. still it is showing me error. "Run time error 13 Type mismatch"

Comment: Change the source data part to: `SourceData:="'Raw data'!" & Range("A1").CurrentRegion.address(referencestyle:=xlr1c1)`